# Android Studio - Error importing project Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Till now I have been using Eclipse IDE, but now I changed PC and I have a lot of troubles with setting up Eclipse again. So I decided to use Android Studio. I am trying to import one project but I get an error during the build..

Error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Unsupported type 'alpha' in file /Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/Test/app/src/main/res/Anim/fade_in.xml
```

I am totally new to Android Studio and I am lost a lot..

This is my file fade_in.xml:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:fillAfter="true">
     <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" 
            android:toAlpha="1.0"
            android:duration="2000"/>
</set>
```

I tried to clean the project but with no success.I still get this error.

In the folder `Gradle scripts` I have 2 build.gradle files (I don't know if this is ok)

I have: 1.) build.gradle (Module app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "test.android"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
}
```

2.) build.gradle (Project Test):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: Your folder name is wrong `Anim`. make it `anim`. it's working fine with me.

Comment: Look like it helped..now I have 146 new errors while building the project..I will try to figure it out what is going on..and then probably write another question here :/