# 'Unsupported type error' after importing Android project to Android Studio

Tags: java, android, eclipse

(*I am new to forum so please ignore any mistake while posting. I have already tried alot to tackle this error.*)
I am new (Intern) to android. My boss asked me make some changes in existing Eclipse project.

For importing project to Android Studio, I commented out the following lines in project.properties file

```
#android.library.reference.1=..\\google-play-services_lib
#android.library.reference.2=../androidv7-appcompatz
```

Project successfully imported and I added dependencies.

Upon building the project I got the following error

```
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
E:\Workspace\Intern\Quran\AlAjmi\app\src\main\res\values\category_lists.xml
Error:Error: Unsupported type 'category_list'
:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> E:\Workspace\Intern\Quran\AlAjmi\app\src\main\res\values\category_lists.xml: Error: Unsupported type 'category_list'
Information:BUILD FAILED
```

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3Aen.png)

Here is category_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item type="category_list" name="row">false</item>
</resources>
```

I don't know the types and files declared in values folder. Please have a look and elaborate.

[Screenshot of values folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjrVj.png)

**Details that may be of some relevance**.

I am using Android Studio 2.1.2

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.saturnteam.best.islamic.app.quran"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <!-- for APPNEXT adds -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.saturnteam.best.islamic.app.quran.HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.saturnteam.best.islamic.app.quran.AudioListActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.saturnteam.best.islamic.app.quran.InfoActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.saturnteam.best.islamic.app.quran.PlayAudioFile"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance" >
        </activity>

        <service android:name="com.saturnteam.best.islamic.app.quran.MediaPlayerService" />

        <!-- for APPNEXT adds -->
        <service android:name="com.appnext.appnextsdk.DownloadService" />

        <!-- for  HEYZAP -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.heyzap.sdk.ads.HeyzapInterstitialActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />

        <receiver android:name="com.heyzap.sdk.ads.PackageAddedReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <data android:scheme="package" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- for ADDMOBE adds add this below Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**build.gradle**(app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.saturnteam.best.islamic.app.quran"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1'
    compile files('libs/AppnextSDK.jar')
    compile files('libs/heyzap-ads-sdk-7.2.4.jar')
}
```

[Android Studio - Error importing project Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31338585/android-studio-error-importing-project-errorexecution-failed-for-task-appm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error states `"category_list"` is not a valid resource value `type`. (even in Eclipse, so Gradle is doing you a favor here)

Your options are booleans, integers, strings, dimensions, etc.

You can see the full list of [valid types](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html) for more detail.

Perhaps, you meant this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="category_list_row">false</bool>
</resources>
```

Comment: I really appreciate! i can't figure out why are there .xml files in values folder having different types as there names.